# Subjunctive mood: "Be not" vs. "not be"

Tags: meaning, difference, word-order, subjunctives

Which is correct?

> The Senate has decided that such students ...... [be not / not be] exempted from college.

Please clarify it with grammatical rules, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The negative subjunctive is formed by putting *not* before the verb, at least nowadays, as indicated in e.g. this Q&A on our sister site English Language & Usage: [What's the correct form of the negative subjunctive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/197130/116151). (That seems to imply it used to be the other way around.)

That means the sentence should be

> The Senate has decided that such students not be exempted from college.

Comment: But I think in case of 'be' verb, either "not be" or "be not" may be used. In grammar there are no whys always. Let's see what the native speakers of English usually say.